# Adding and replacing text in a string at once in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code which puts   « » brackets around the selected text, meanwhile I have another code which replaces Urdu text to Arabic text on selection , both functions are separate. I want to use both function with one button only which will add   « in start of text and » in the end of text and simultaneously replace the Urdu Alphabets with Arabic Alphabets.. 
TIA

Comment: Maybe if you edit the question and show some code will be better for write an answer

Comment: so write a new function to do what you want

Comment: please add the code you have. maybe you have a look here [mcve]

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: here is the code:

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have 2 seperate methods for those 2 functions. Then simply call those two methods from button's onClick event.

HTML:
`< button onclick="onClickHandler()">Click< /button>`

JS:

```
'<script>
function onClickHandler() {
    putBrackets();
    changeTextToArabic();
}

function putBrackets(){
...
}
</script>'
```

Comment: I had did this , but not successful

Answer (score 0):

//First Function to insert "«" and "»"

```
function ArabicBracket4() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById("textareaid4");
        var artext=textarea.value.substring;
    if ('selectionStart' in textarea) {
        // check whether some text is selected in the textarea
        if (textarea.selectionStart != textarea.selectionEnd) {
         var newText = textarea.value.substring(0, textarea.selectionStart) +
                "«" + textarea.value.substring(textarea.selectionStart, textarea.selectionEnd) + "»" +
                textarea.value.substring(textarea.selectionEnd);
                textarea.value = newText;
        }
    } else { // Internet Explorer before version 9
        // create a range from the current selection
        var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
        // check whether the selection is within the textarea
        var rangeParent = textRange.parentElement();
        if (rangeParent === textarea) {
            textRange.text = "«" + textRange.text + "»";
        }
    }
    //2nd Function to change Urdu Alphabets to Arabic

    function PureArabic4() {
    var txtarea = document.getElementById("textareaid4");
    var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
    var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
    var s = txtarea.value.substring(start, finish);
    s = s.replace(/آ/g, "آ");
    s = s.replace(/ا/g, "ا");
    s = s.replace(/ب/g, "ب");
    s = s.replace(/پ/g, "پ");
    s = s.replace(/ت/g, "ت");
    s = s.replace(/ٹ/g, "ٹ");
    s = s.replace(/ث/g, "ث");
    s = s.replace(/ج/g, "ج");
    s = s.replace(/چ/g, "چ");
    s = s.replace(/خ/g, "خ");
    s = s.replace(/ح/g, "ح");
    s = s.replace(/د/g, "د");
    s = s.replace(/ڈ/g, "ڈ");
    s = s.replace(/ذ/g, "ذ");
    s = s.replace(/ر/g, "ر");
    s = s.replace(/ڑ/g, "ڑ");
    s = s.replace(/ز/g, "ز");
    s = s.replace(/ژ/g, "ژ");
    s = s.replace(/س/g, "س");
    s = s.replace(/ش/g, "ش");
    s = s.replace(/ص/g, "ص");
    s = s.replace(/ض/g, "ض");
    s = s.replace(/ط/g, "ط");
    s = s.replace(/ظ/g, "ظ");
    s = s.replace(/ع/g, "ع");
    s = s.replace(/غ/g, "غ");
    s = s.replace(/ف/g, "ف");
    s = s.replace(/ک/g, "ك");
    s = s.replace(/ق/g, "ق");
    s = s.replace(/گ/g, "گ");
    s = s.replace(/ل/g, "ل");
    s = s.replace(/م/g, "م");
    s = s.replace(/ن/g, "ن");
    s = s.replace(/و/g, "و");
    s = s.replace(/ہ/g, "ه");
    s = s.replace(/ء/g, "ء");
    s = s.replace(/ی/g, "ي");
    s = s.replace(/ئ/g, "ئ");
    s = s.replace(/ے/g, "ے");
    s = s.replace(/ۃ/g, "ة");
    s = s.replace(/ؤ/g, "ؤ");
    s = s.replace(/إ/g, "إ");
    s = s.replace(/أ/g, "أ");
    }
```

Comment: Any method to join the both functions in one?